# lapply - dividing columns and calculate standard deviation

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have got a list with 10 data.frames and I just need to divide two columns for each data.frame and after calculate the relative standard deviation.

I would like to use lapply.

Here an example of one of the data.frame contained within the list:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'X   Y
2     4
5     3 
1     2
7     1
4     2
6     1', header = TRUE)
```

I have to perform the following operations with lapply for all my 10 data.frames:

```
ratio <- df$X / df$Y
sd <- sd(ratio)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by looping over the `list` with `lapply`, extract the columns of interest, divide to get the 'ratio' and then do the `sd` on that ratio.  (It could be done on a single step too)

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {ratio <- x$X/x$Y
                        sd(ratio) })
```

where 'lst' is the `list` of 'data.frame's.